Error Building PostgreSQL from Source: Undefined ICU References During make world-bin
I am trying to build PostgreSQL from source on my Linux machine but am encountering errors related to ICU during the make world-bin process. Below are the details of what I've done so far:
Steps Taken:
sudo yum install libicu-devel

git clone git://git.postgresql.org/git/postgresql.git
./configure --enable-tap-tests --prefix=`pwd`/build
make world-bin

Issues
During the make world-bin process, I encountered the following error messages indicating undefined references to ICU functions:
/usr/bin/ld: pg_locale.c:(.text+0x1701): undefined reference to `ucol_getRules_73'
/usr/bin/ld: pg_locale.c:(.text+0x1724): undefined reference to `u_strlen_73'
/usr/bin/ld: pg_locale.c:(.text+0x1739): undefined reference to `u_strlen_73'
/usr/bin/ld: pg_locale.c:(.text+0x1757): undefined reference to `u_strcpy_73'
/usr/bin/ld: pg_locale.c:(.text+0x1764): undefined reference to `u_strcat_73'
... (more similar errors)
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make[2]: *** [Makefile:67: postgres] Error 1

I have ICU version 73.1 installed and confirmed with:
icu-config --version

My ~/.zshrc file includes the following configurations:
export LDFLAGS="-L/usr/lib64"
export CPPFLAGS="-I/usr/include"
export PATH="/usr/lib64/icu:$PATH"
export PKG_CONFIG_PATH="/usr/lib64/pkgconfig/"
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH="/usr/local/lib:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH"

I have also sourced the .zshrc file after making these changes.
What might be causing these ICU-related errors, and how can I resolve them to successfully build PostgreSQL?

In which directory is libicui18n.so?

When querying sudo find / -name libicui18n.so I got two results: /usr/lib64/libicui18n.so and /usr/local/lib/libicui18n.so

Then perhaps there is a mixup, and configure finds one installation when it looks for the headers and the other when it tries to ling PostgreSQL. Look at the configure output to figure out where the headers are found and set LDPATH so that it finds the appropriate libraries.
